# EF Database First with ASP.NET MVC - data validation for "Allow null false"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I use EF Database First with ASP.NET MVC, But I see that data validations are auto generated only for integer and datetime fields. 
Shouldn't it generate validation automatically for varchar() field which are mandatory (where allow null is set as false in database)

Comment: I mean client side data validation(javascript validation)

Comment: i had to do it manually  in my last project;I used Metadataclasses and Unobtrusive.

Comment: Your model property needs a `[Required]` attribute

Comment: I haven't added [Required] attribute  on my int field, still client side validation works for those?

Comment: Yes, because `int` and `DateTime` must have a value (they can never be `null`) - but a `string` can be

Comment: any other option to enable validation for string fields without adding attributes explicitly?

Comment: If you want it to be required, then you must add a `[Required]` attribute